JavaScript Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (id.php?userPhone=123:93:23)
I am trying to create a user ID card web page that displays user information which was received via the backend. I also have to add a button below the id card which allows users to download the ID card to their device locally so I tried using the jsPDF library but that did not seem to work. The following is the code for the whole web page:
I got the following error and output in the console:
Button clicked!
id.php?userPhone=123:93 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (id.php?userPhone=123:93:23)



document.getElementById('downloadBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("Button clicked!");
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.html(document.querySelector('.id-card-container'), {
    callback: function(pdf) {
      pdf.save('id_card.pdf');
      console.log("PDF saved!");
    }
  });
});
.id-card-container {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

.id-card-header,
.id-card-footer {
  background: #343a40;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.id-card-header img {
  max-width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.id-card-body {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.id-card-body h5 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.id-card-body p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn-download {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="main" class="container-fluid">

  <div class="id-card-container">
    <div class="id-card-header">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Company Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="id-card-body">
      <h5>ID Card Information</h5>
      <p><strong>ID Card Number: </strong>ID 1</p>
      <p><strong>Date of Issue: </strong>Date 1</p>
      <p><strong>Full Name: </strong>Firstname Lastname</p>
      <p><strong>Date of Birth: </strong>DOB</p>
      <p><strong>Craft Name: </strong>Craaftname</p>
      <p><strong>Aadhar No: </strong>Aadharnum</p>
      <p><strong>Contact No: </strong>Phone</p>
      <p><strong>Address: </strong>User address</p>
    </div>
    <div class="id-card-footer">
      <p>Valid for 5 years from the date of issue</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="downloadBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-download">Download ID Card as PDF</button>
  </div>
</div>




Try replacing var doc = new jsPDF(); with var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();.

@KJ Cannot find "/dist/jspdf.min.js" in jspdf@2.5.1

@KIKOSoftware html.js:51 Uncaught (in promise)
Error: Could not load html2canvas: Error: Could not load html2canvas
at html.js:51:31
(anonymous) @ html.js:51
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ html.js:750
u.thenCore @ html.js:783
u.then @ html.js:738
u.doCallback @ html.js:598
r.html @ html.js:1035
(anonymous) @ id.php?userPhone=123

I made a snippet for you without unnecessary PHP to have a [mcve]

The issues usually stem from changes in the distributed scripts thus best to use the latest, so as to last a while.
The CDN js.PDF.js is tied with reference to the HTML2Canvas.js thus when one loading error is cleared you likely get a different one! Thus took several attempts to get a working set. So firstly go to the CDN and ensure you get both the latest client versions.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-qZvrmS2ekKPF2mSznTQsxqPgnpkI4DNTlrdUmTzrDgektczlKNRRhy5X5AAOnx5S09ydFYWWNSfcEqDTTHgtNA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js" integrity="sha512-BNaRQnYJYiPSqHHDb58B0yaPfCu+Wgds8Gp/gU33kqBtgNS4tSPHuGibyoeqMV/TJlSKda6FXzoEyYGjTe+vXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


For the jsPDF loading issue you need to consider altering 2 lines. Commonly jspdf is used lowercase so need defining as such and there are several options but here is the simplest. And when defining units the recommended unit is 'pt' for use with canvas.
The two lines could be combined as var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF('p', 'pt', [350,590]); The choice of values is down to "Design" thus not a programming issue. Except HTML has a tendency to overflow to a second page if you don't check in multiple browsers for differences in rounding off!
<script>
document.getElementById('downloadBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("Button clicked!");
  jspdf = jspdf.jsPDF;
  var doc = new jspdf('p', 'pt', [350,590]);
  doc.html(document.querySelector('.id-card-container'), {
    callback: function(pdf) {
      pdf.save('id_card.pdf');
      console.log("PDF saved!");
    }
  });
});
</script>

